# iOS Grab Random Entry From XML File

Tags: ios, xml, json

I am working on displaying a random Bible verse from a KJV XML file that I have, but am having some issues with the formatting of the XML, as it essentially has numerous arrays within it.  It has a format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bible translation="King James Version">
    <testament name="Old">
        <book name="Genesis">
            <chapter number="1">
                <verse number="1">
                </verse>
            </chapter>
        </book>
     </testament>
 </bible>
```

I have tried getting this converted to a plist file to handle it better, but am running into issues on that front as well.  I used an online program to convert this to JSON file, but when using `plutil` from terminal to convert to a `plist` file, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected character { at line 1 / JSON error: No string key for value in object around character 1.
```

The JSON format looks like this for the first few lines:

```
{
  "bible": {
    "-translation": "King James Version",
    "testament": [
      {
        "-name": "Old",
        "book": [
          {
            "-name": "Genesis",
            "chapter": [
              {
                "-number": "1",
                "verse": [
                  {
                    "-number": "1",
                    "#text": "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
                  },
```

I would appreciate any suggestions, either on converting this to a `plist` file, or to making it work with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a 3rd party lib is no issue:

Use a xml parser to parse the incoming xml to a dictionary.

i.e. https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

The simplest way to load an XML file using this lib is as follows:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someFile" ofType:@"xml"];
NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLFile:filePath];
```

Also converting into dictionary will give you advantage of grabbing any random data you desire.

I hope this helps.